# Customize ANOVA table in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, anova

Is there a way to customize the way ANOVA table look ? Without to much effort manipulating each element of the list ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `Grid[(ANOVA /. yourresult)]` and the various styling options for Grids [described in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html). (see also the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumnsOverview.html))

If there is a hidden `TableForm` on the right hand side of that rule, you might need to do something like `Grid[InputForm[(ANOVA /. yourresult)]]`.

Comment: There is a hidden `TableForm`.

Comment: There's indeed a TableForm hidden in the result, but you don't need InputForm to get rid of it (it doesn't work either I think). Just dig in the output using Part [[ ... ]] to find the data and use that with Grid