# Change the Background of a "Parameter Table" in Mathematica

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica, presentation

Please consider :

```
listA = {5, 10, 6, 9, 10, 9, 8, 0, 4, 2};
listB = {2, 8, 7, 1, 7, 6, 10, 5, 1, 5};

Column[Function[listNo, 
                LinearModelFit[listNo, x, x]["ParameterTable"]] /@ 
                {listA, listB}]
```

[image]

Following a previous question on  [Customize ANOVA Table in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425696/customize-anova-table-in-mathematica), I would like to know How can I change the background of the above. I would like each to have a different background color.

Using Belisarius trick I was able to do the below, however, now they are colored, I realize those table are not the same size. Please let me know if there is a way around that display problem.

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Yes I did and corrected as well. I am puzzled your comment was 4 minutes ago, and I edited that mistake 17 minutes ago !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
Column[Style[#[[1]], Background -> #[[2]]] 
     & /@  ({LinearModelFit[#[[1]], x, x]["ParameterTable"], #[[2]]} 
          & /@ {{listA, Yellow}, {listB, Red}})]
```

[image]

**Edit**

You'll have to work this out a little more if you want a straight ending. Something like:

```
listA = {5, 10, 6, 9, 10, 9, 8, 0, 4, 2};
listB = {2, 8, 7, 1, 7, 6, 10, 5, 1, 5};
tit = {"", "Estimate", "Standard Error", "t\[Hyphen]Statistic", 
   "P\[Hyphen]Value"};


Grid[Flatten[
  Join[{{tit}}, (Join[{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]] & /@ 
       Partition[(Riffle[#["BasisFunctions"], #["ParameterTableEntries"]] &@ 
                  LinearModelFit[#, x, x]), 2] & /@ {listA, listB})], 1], 
 Background -> {{White, {None}}, {None, {Pink, Pink, Yellow, Yellow}}}, 
 Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}, 
 Frame -> {{True}, {True}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[2], Blue]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much belisarius !

Comment: I need your help again :-). Please look at my edit. How could I make it straight and better :-) ?

Comment: Hey Sorry, something went wrong. Please see the edit now. Let me know if I can get those straight.

Comment: Thank you belisarius ! this is so helpfull